# JSF Ajax session time out issue while opening a dialog box

Tags: jsf

Am developing a project using jsf2.2+primefaces 4.0,

I have an issue with opening dialog box even session timeout in jsf.

I have opened two tabs in same browser and in first tab am logged out from the session, in another tab(second) am opening a dialog box, it should be redirect to login but its opening a dialog.

How can I check if session is available or not while opening a dialog?

Please help me on this its great thankful to you.

Regards
Ravindra

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `SessionFilter` to check if there is a logged user or not. In the `doFilter()` method of your SessionFilter, you should add this control:

```
if (session == null || session.getAttribute("id") == null) {
        response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
}
```

And don't forget to configure your web.xml. This link may help you https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info .